# My syslog is full of errors from NetworkManager about setting the MTU for wireless adapter

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, ipv6, mtu

NetworkManager keeps trying to set the MTU for my wifi connection to `9216` and then complain about it:

```
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469713916.019478] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
```

`wlp3s0` is my wireless adapter. I cannot find any configuration file that requests an MTU of `9216`.

I've tried setting both `MTU` and `IPV6_MTU` to `1500` in my `ifcfg` file for the AP in question (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-MY_SSID_NAME`):

```
IPV6_MTU="1500"
MTU="1500"
```

I even see NetworkManager acknowledging this in syslog:

```
NetworkManager[9173]: <info>  (wlp3s0): Lowering IPv6 MTU (9216) to match device MTU (1500)
```

Which is then a few seconds later followed by a bout of:

```
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469714284.500691] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469714287.572734] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469714300.474736] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469714319.725995] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469714336.521603] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
NetworkManager[9173]: <error> [1469714339.470093] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2489] sysctl_set(): platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu' to '9216': (22) Invalid argument
```

....etc...

Assuming this request came from the router, I've turned off `accept_ra` and `accept_ra_mtu`:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/accept_ra
0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/accept_ra_mtu
0
```

...to no avail...

I can't seem to find references to this, or consistent documentation on MTU settings. The message `Lowering IPv6 MTU (9216) to match device MTU (1500)` seems to imply that `9216` is an IPv6-wide setting.

Seeing mentions that the MTU `ifcfg` settings might be a ceiling (and thus this is the cause of the error), I've also tried setting them all to `9216` with no change in the frequency of errors.

In fact, it seems that `1500` is the limit (even with the change to `9216` in the config scripts):

```
# echo "1500" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu
# echo "1501" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu
  -bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
# echo "1400" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/mtu
#
```

This is on a ThinkPad W540 running Fedora 22:

```
# uname -a
Linux my_machine.my_domain.com 4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 24 21:19:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: First bring your system up to date. The amount of support available for end-of-life operating systems is very limited.